# Using Named Credentials in Batch Job (multi user)

Tags: namedcredentials

Named credentials are working good in single user scenario, where we are making callouts on behalf of a given user.

In a recent requirement, we need to setup a "PER USER" Named Credential, which requires each user to login and authorize separately.

The same Named Credential needs to be consumed in a Salesforce batch job, where we will sync up data of multiple users every mid night.

I am not able to figure out a way to make the a HTTP callout in Apex, and making that Named Credential work for a given user.  Is it possible ?

If you believe the problem can't be solved, please up-vote this related idea : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3exQAC

Comment: Tough one! Could a feasible workaround be using an Inbound Email Service to start the various jobs and the context of the correct user?

Comment: Not sure but this blog also use [per user auth in apex](http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2015/03/named-credential-and-auth-provider.html)

Comment: @bigassforce cool trick, but sending multiple emails to all inbound users will not work, we are doing it for AppExchange. If NamedCredentials fail for this basic usecase, I might need to fall back to class DIY OAuth 2 :-(

Comment: I think original problem here is you cannot run an apex batch apex with specific user . Wondering if a class scheduled via standard UI can have user context

Comment: @MohithShrivastava thanks, again core problem stays the same, the job will only run for the specific user's named credentials.

Comment: I guess unless you provide a button or a user Interface to invoke the job per user this will be not possible .

Comment: This should be on IdeaExchange, hope you guys will support ?

Comment: Here is link to the idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3exQAC